# Migrating text file data to excel using xlsxwriter is not updating completely

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

test.txt:
A 25 12345
B 90 67890
C 31 24680
D 89 45678

expected output:
A1 A
A2 25
A3 12345
A4 B
A5 90
A6 67890
......

only last three data is coming in the excel

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        for j,k in enumerate(i.split()):
            worksheet.write('A'+str(j+1), k)
    workbook.close()
```

Comment: You don't need the `.readlines()`, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the inner loop, `j` will always be the enumeration `0,1,2` and so you are repeatedly writing to cells `A1`,`A2`, and `A3`. You can see this for yourself if you print the result to your console:

```
A1 A
A2 25
A3 12345
A1 B
A2 90
A3 67890
A1 C
A2 31
A3 24680
A1 D
A2 89
A3 45678
```

You always want to increase the number in the first argument of `write` so the next row gets indexed; the value to increase with is the length of the splitted list (`3` for your current input but to make sure I use the *actual* length of each line below). Because Excel starts counting rows at `1`, this counter needs to start with `1` as well. This will work:

```
counter = 1
for i in f.readlines():
    for j,k in enumerate(i.split()):
         worksheet.write('A'+str(j+counter), k)
    counter += len(i.split())
```

Like your own code and the expected output, all it will do is fill the first column only, with each value in the input, ignoring the line breaks.